# Difficult hover on split image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image, that is split down the middle, with a left pane and right pane. Each side has a unique link and it's own hover.

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="position: relative;">
    <div>
        <div class="jumbo-title">
            <p runat="server">Title</p>
        </div>            
        <a id="leftPane" class="jumbo-hover" runat="server" target="_blank">
            <div>
                <p>Summary</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="rightPane" class="jumbo-hover" runat="server" target="_blank">
            <div>
                <p>Full Report</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <img src="/assets/home.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.jumbo-hover {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#MainContent_rightPane {
    right:0;
}

#MainContent_leftPane {
    left: 0;
}

.jumbo-hover:hover {
    background-color: rgba(16, 89, 121, 0.48);
}
.jumbo-hover:hover div p {
    color: #cbf305;
}
.jumbotron p
{
    line-height:1.15em
}
.jumbotron a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.jumbo-title
{
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    z-index:1000;
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-left:30%;
    text-shadow: 1px 4px 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
    font-weight:bold;            
}
#MainContent_leftPane div 
{
    width:30%; 
    height:20%; 
    margin-top:69%; 
    margin-left:64%; 
    color:white;
    font-family:'Playfair Display';
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:right;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height:0.9em;
}
#MainContent_rightPane div 
{
    width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-top: 69%;
    margin-left: 6%;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Playfair Display';
    font-size:32px;
    text-align:left;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height:0.9em;    
}
```

My problem is only that when I hover the .jumbo-title, I lose the highlighting of the right or left pane respectively. How can I move up the css chain while still hovering and highlighting the proper side of the image?

Thanks so much!

Comment: seems like some of the relevant code is missing http://jsfiddle.net/hdky0s86/ A working example would be useful!

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/VH1DfSZ.jpg)

Comment: it seems like the title should be underneath your anchors, but as I said, please provide a fiddle or something that reproduces what you have so far (the ids in your css don't seem to match the HTML for starters).

Comment: My IDs had some ASP in them.. removed. http://jsfiddle.net/hdky0s86/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your title is laying on top of your 2 links. I see two options to solve this:

**option 1: add `pointer-events: none` to you title**

```
.jumbo-title { pointer-events: none; }
```

disadvantage of this is the poor support in IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events
in any descent browser it will work though: http://jsfiddle.net/hdky0s86/2/

**option 2: move your title underneath your links**

the most easy way for this is probably to work with the z-index, since you are already positioning absolute. just remove the z-index from your `.jumbo-title` and add one to your `.jumbo-hover` (and no need for it to be 1000, 1 will do)

http://jsfiddle.net/hdky0s86/3/

This should work fine in any browser, but your 'hover' color will be on top of your title, which is probably not desirable.

---

*As a side note, I have the feeling you are over complicating things, especially when it comes to your HTML. Have a look at the example I set up, that does basically the same with a fraction of the code you use...*

```
<div class='split-image-wrapper'>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <a class='left'>summary</a>
    <a class='right'>full report</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdky0s86/4/

Comment: Does your edit work with an image that isn't static? The image path I use is dynamic.

Comment: sure, just add it as a style attribute on the div in stead of in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get a little help from your friend jQuery. If you add a listener on your title to watch for hovers, and then toggle a class `hovered` to your `#rightPane` when title is hovered, you can keep the hovered styles on:

```
$(".jumbo-title").hover(
    function(){
        $("#rightPane").toggleClass("hovered");
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
.jumbo-hover:hover, .hovered {
    background-color: rgba(16, 89, 121, 0.48);
}
.jumbo-hover:hover div p, .hovered div p {
    color: #cbf305;
}
```